# png images getting streached inside imageview

Tags: android, imageview

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="@dimen/contactUsPad"
    tools:context="com.onqanetapp.mp.onqanet.ContactUs_Fragment">

    <!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".2"
        android:text="@string/contactUsAddHead"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/contactUsAdd"
        android:textSize="18sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".6"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivFb"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/socialImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/socialImageHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/socialImageRightMargin"
            android:src="@drawable/f" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivIn"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/socialImageWidth"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/socialImageHeight"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/socialImageRightMargin"
            android:src="@drawable/in" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivTw"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/socialImageRightMargin"
            android:src="@drawable/tw" />
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

### dimens

```
<dimen name="socialImageHeight">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="socialImageWidth">50dp</dimen>
<dimen name="socialImageRightMargin">10dp</dimen>
```

### Image

[this is final layout screenshot and i did't change the last imageview to show you guys the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qIxi.png)

### info

1. all images are png
2. first drawable start's at 48x48

#### question

1. wrap_content should  give those images there resolution i.e 48x48 , but it's not.
2. when i give them width and height of 50dp they looks stretched but
   also looks out of bounds.
3. also tired 72x72 resolution  but same

Comment: use this property to `ImageView` `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

Comment: you are not following the layout rules properly, please fix it first.

Comment: @AshishShukla ...can you specify what ... i am new to Android .

Comment: @Mrin You are not using the android:layout_weight property properly.

Answer (score 0):

try to add following lines in imageView xml :

```
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"; //fitCenter, or change according to your requirement
```

For Scaling the bounds of an image view:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType.html

Answer (score 0):

You have to adjust the image bounds according to the screen size.

```
android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

It wont strech or crop image. It will simply resize the image

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers guys .

but nothing works for me.whatever i do the image steal not crisp or clear so i use SVG.

## ===========

downloaded svg icons from http://www.flaticon.com/

then used Vector Asset Studio(https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio.html)

(Right-click the **res** folder and select **New** > **Vector Asset**.)
to import SVG to vector asset studio which then convert the svg to drawable xml.
now it's work like a charm.